# Tab refresh is not working in lighting component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, tab, refresh

### Controller:

```
handleSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({"title": "Success!","message": "The property's info has been updated.","type": "success"});
        toastEvent.fire();
        helper.showHide(component);
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
}
```

### Component:

```
<aura:component controller="process" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Name" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="casepa" type="case"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
    <aura:attribute name="Indexes" default="{ 'sobjectType'}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Component**

```
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>
```

**Controller**

```
handleSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({"title": "Success!","message": "The property's info has been updated.","type": "success"});
    toastEvent.fire();
    helper.showHide(component);

    workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
        var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
        workspaceAPI.refreshTab({
                  tabId: focusedTabId,
                  includeAllSubtabs: true
         });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```